# Using a subquery in SELECT returns an error that I can't interpret

Tags: sql

I have a table with order ids and I am trying to figure out the value/count 
 of those who came through facebook compared to those who didn't. As you see I put a subquery in the select which (on its own) shows the count of those who did not come through facebook. But as a subquery i get an error.

How do I fix this? Why is it not working?

```
SELECT
  cs.country AS country, 
  COUNT(ltv.eco_id) AS count_ltv_fb,
  ROUND(AVG(ltv.lifetime)/(365/12), 2) AS avg_life_months,
  CONCAT('$ ', ROUND(AVG(fb.click_cost), 4)) AS click_cost,
  CONCAT('$ ', ROUND(SUM(ltv.disc_ltv)/COUNT(distinct ltv.eco_id), 2)) AS disc_ltv,
  COUNT(distinct ltv.eco_id) AS gns_count,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT l.eco_id)
    FROM published.company_status AS c
    LEFT JOIN channel_analytics.facebook_ads_event AS f 
      ON f.order_id = sha2(CAST(c.company_id AS string),256)
    LEFT JOIN ltv.ltv_forecast AS l 
      ON TRIM(SUBSTRING(l.eco_id,INSTR(l.eco_id,'|')+1)) = c.company_id
  ) AS count_ltv_not_fb
FROM published.company_status AS cs
LEFT JOIN channel_analytics.facebook_ads_event AS fb 
  ON fb.order_id = sha2(CAST(cs.company_id AS string),256)
LEFT JOIN ltv.ltv_forecast AS ltv 
  ON TRIM(SUBSTRING(ltv.eco_id,INSTR(ltv.eco_id,'|')+1)) = cs.company_id
WHERE fb.order_id IS NOT NULL
  AND ltv.lifetime IS NOT NULL
  AND cs.country in ('Australia', 'United States', 'Canada', 'United Kingdom')
GROUP BY cs.country
ORDER BY gns_count DESC
```

Error Msg

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 9:0 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'COUNT' '(' in expression specification

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Neither database supports `cast(<x> as string)` so the database is a bit of a mystery.

Comment: it's sql-server. Pretty sure...

Comment: I think it Hive not sql the error is comming from.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that is a custom internal thing.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add the FROM before the subquery.  It looks like Redshift (maybe using SQL Workbench?)

Edit:

Down voted? I didn't realize you were using a nested query until I wrote out the code. Have you tried putting the distinct before the count in the nested query? Also, you should add which type of SQL (PGSQL/TSQL) and which system you're using (Toad/MySQL/SQL Server/Workbench/Oracle/Toad/etc.).